# GZIP compression working only on HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, gzip

Is the Google Chrome and Firefox blocking GZIP compression on HTTP sites? I noticed that only HTTPS sites contain the "Content-Encoding: gzip" response header. The browser apparently does not use GZIP on HTTP sites.

I researched and found nothing about it! I only found in old threads that HTTPS compression is insecure.

Comment: I have just found the same thing. We spent hours on curl trying to figure out why we were not getting gzip files in the browser.

Comment: The same here. I have been debugging nginx for almost two days, trying to figure it out. Curl gzip testing works fine, but Chrome always returns uncompressed response headers for http sites. Adding 'https://' to the URL makes it work, even if there is no SSL certificate.